# What Devices are Selected in a Xcode Managed Provisioning Profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

Is there I way where I can see what devices are included in an Provisioning Profile Managed by Xcode? I've added some devices to my account, and when I refreshed the provisioning profiles in Xcode Preferences, I saw that it created a new Provisioning Profile with the same, but with a new expiration date (even though the previous one was removed from the management portal, it is still listed in Xcode).

Then, when I come back to check the Profile in the Portal, I see that it lists the total number of devices that I actually have registered on my Account. I would like to know if this is the default behaviour, if in all Provisioning Profiles managed by Xcode it will include all registered devices. If so, is there some way to change what devices are included, or for this I'll need to create the provision manually?

**Update:**
I just realized that my question just make senses because I was thinking of distribution (ad-hoc), and Xcode Managed Provisioning Profiles are used in Development provisions, which makes senses for the actual developers working on it. When exporting an App archive, we need to actually select a distribution Provision Profile, which will then be managed in the developer portal and allow device selection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways view which devices are provisioned with a particular provisioning profile:

1. iPhone Configuration Utility, just select the provision profile and it will list the provisioned devices. http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone configuration utility
2. In terminal type in `security cms -D -i <path to the provisioning profile>` this will print out all the details of the provisioning profile including the devices.

Comment: Very useful! Thanks on the reference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment you. So i'm saying here.You can manage devices in xcode.
 Select windows >organizer.

source:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/provision_device_for_development-generic.html

Answer (score 0):

Well all devices you added are available.
Otherwise as mentioned go to Organizer -> Devices, you there see on the left side all devices you used for development / which are activated.